# cocoa:The location of the settings window on the screen

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

```
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(110.0, 0, 100, 100) display:NO];
```

Write positioning has no effect。Ask for help

I want to set the window position。 x  and y  Did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to set just window's x and y possition You need to use `setFrameOrigin`.

**For example:**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [windowOutlet setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(0,0)];
}
```

** Don't forget to **IBOutlet** Your window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `[self setFrame:CGRectMake(110.0, 0, 100, 100) display:YES];`?